# read the Membership/Profile/Role provider's connection from external file other then web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my MVC application I am reading the Membership/Profile/Role provider's connection string from web.config. In web.config I am writing this connection string at runtime.
  Now the problem is, if I update the web.config at run time, then each time my application will get restarted, it will slow down my application.

So I want to read the  Membership/Profile/Role provider's connection string  from any external file, other then web.config. Because if that external file is updated at run time, will not cause the application restart .

So please suggest me the way to read the connection string for role provider from external file .

Thanks in Advance
Aayushi

---

Can I get the connection string for role provider from external file , but not from web.config

Comment: I believe if you update the connectionstring without reloading then you wont have the correct connectionstring.

Comment: How often are you updating the Web.config? Is there a reason you will need to be updating the web.config so often that it causes problems with your users? Generally at least with the apps I've worked on my web.config being overwritten doesn't affect the performance of my app, and I generally keep my connection strings in it, or in their own db.config file that the web.config references.

Answer (score 0):

The `SqlMembershipProvider` relies on the web.config to retrieve connection string settings, and will throw an exception of the connection string is not provided via the ASP.NET configuration model.

That said, `SqlMembershipProvider` is not a sealed class. You could override its initialization behavior to achieve an effect similar to what you describe.

If you have a finite number of connection strings, as might be the case if you are trying to manage connection strings at different stages (e.g., dev, test, production, etc.), you might include *all your connection strings* in your web.config, each with its own name, and implement some runtime logic to switch between them in a custom provider.

```
public class CustomSqlMembershipProvider : SqlMembershipProvider
{
    public override void Initialize(string name, NameValueCollection config)
    {
        string connStringName = // retrieve from wherever you please...
        config["connectionStringName"] = connStringName;
        base.Initialize(name, config);
    }
}
```

The limitation of this approach is clear if you need to support arbitrarily many connection strings. Even so, you can still build a custom membership provider with behavior like the SqlMembershipProvider via inheritance if you override the `Initialize` method and sufficiently replace its internal behavior.

Good luck.